# how to create a print dialog box in python3

Tags: printing

I am novice in python and on my way to completing my first desktop application. I have some reports but don't know how to send them to printer with the click of a button

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example I got from PyQT's website. It helped me out quite a bit. You will have to install pip and PyQT5
from the command prompt type:
pip install PyQT5

```
 import sys, os
 from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtPrintSupport

 class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
     def __init__(self):
         super(Window, self).__init__()
         self.setWindowTitle('Document Printer')
         self.editor = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
         self.editor.textChanged.connect(self.handleTextChanged)
         self.buttonOpen = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Open', self)
         self.buttonOpen.clicked.connect(self.handleOpen)
         self.buttonPrint = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Print', self)
         self.buttonPrint.clicked.connect(self.handlePrint)
         self.buttonPreview = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Preview', self)
         self.buttonPreview.clicked.connect(self.handlePreview)
         layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
         layout.addWidget(self.editor, 0, 0, 1, 3)
         layout.addWidget(self.buttonOpen, 1, 0)
         layout.addWidget(self.buttonPrint, 1, 1)
         layout.addWidget(self.buttonPreview, 1, 2)
         self.handleTextChanged()

     def handleOpen(self):
         path = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
             self, 'Open file', '',
             'HTML files (*.html);;Text files (*.txt)')[0]
         if path:
             file = QtCore.QFile(path)
             if file.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly):
                 stream = QtCore.QTextStream(file)
                 text = stream.readAll()
                 info = QtCore.QFileInfo(path)
                 if info.completeSuffix() == 'html':
                     self.editor.setHtml(text)
                 else:
                     self.editor.setPlainText(text)
                 file.close()

     def handlePrint(self):
         dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintDialog()
         if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
             self.editor.document().print_(dialog.printer())

     def handlePreview(self):
         dialog = QtPrintSupport.QPrintPreviewDialog()
         dialog.paintRequested.connect(self.editor.print_)
         dialog.exec_()

     def handleTextChanged(self):
         enable = not self.editor.document().isEmpty()
         self.buttonPrint.setEnabled(enable)
         self.buttonPreview.setEnabled(enable)

 if __name__ == '__main__':

     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
     window = Window()
     window.resize(640, 480)
     window.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```